# Comparing Polymorphic Base Types in C++ without RTTI

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have some pointers to a base type of Shape. I want to compare these objects using the == operator. The == operator should obviously return false if the objects are of different derived type. If they are of the same derived type however the members of the derived type should then be compared.

I have read that using the C++ RTTI is bad practice and should only be used in rare and essential circumstances. As far as I can see this problem cannot be generally solved without using the RTTI. Each overloaded == operator would have to check the typeid, and if they are the same perform a dynamic_cast and compare the members. This seems like a common need. Is there some kind of idiom for this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
  public:
    Shape() {}
    virtual ~Shape() {}
    virtual void draw() = 0;

    virtual bool operator == (const Shape &Other) const = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
  public:
    Circle() {}
    virtual ~Circle() {}
    virtual void draw() { cout << "Circle"; }

    virtual bool operator == (const Shape &Other) const {
      // If Shape is a Circle then compare radii
    }

  private:
    int radius;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
  public:
    Rectangle() {}
    virtual ~Rectangle() {}
    virtual void draw() { cout << "Rectangle"; }

    virtual bool operator == (const Shape &Other) const {
      // If Shape is a Rectangle then compare width and height
    }

  private:
    int width;
    int height;
};

int main() {
  Circle circle;
  Rectangle rectangle;

  Shape *Shape1 = &circle;
  Shape *Shape2 = &rectangle;

  (*Shape1) == (*Shape2); // Calls Circle ==
  (*Shape2) == (*Shape1); // Calls Rectangle ==
}
```

Comment: I don't have the time to craft a complete answer, but I'll mention that you may be interested in researching about multi-methods, which is a solution to this problem. In C++, it's not for the faint of heart, mind you.

Comment: What about just using an Enum as your types seems to be aware of other types?

Comment: @ViktorSehr - That is what I have done to solve this problem, but I don't particularly like having to do that

Comment: @oggmonster, i think you should look at
[link](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2008/02/open-multi-methods-for-c.html)
[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7360/MultiMethods-in-C-Finding-a-complete-solution)

Comment: The uncomfortable truth is that RTTI is avoided because it violates an important design principle in OOP: the liskov substitution principle. You simply cannot solve your problem on this level. The only way to compare shapes like you want is by knowing the concrete implementation which is directly opposite to what treating an object as a base-class object is for. Better never lose the type (i.e. store each shape type separately) or use a variant instead of a hierarchy or classes.

Comment: The academical solution would ofcourse be to compare the adresses\data in the v-table.

Comment: @ViktorSehr which is probably what `typeid` does, so why reinvent the wheel? I can ask the same of the OP. Saying "I have read that using the C++ RTTI is bad practice and should only be used in rare and essential circumstances" - overlooks the fact their scenario is _precisely_ where RTTI should be used. Note RTTI encompasses `typeid` + `dynamic_cast`, and as the former is very cheap, I assume the OP's aversion to RTTI overall was based only on things read about the latter. Course `dynamic_cast` should be avoided where possible (like here) if speed is a concern, but it's usually not _that_ bad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the RTTI.
Use `typeid`, but use `static_cast` rather than `dynamic_cast`.

From a design point of view, I'd say that this is exactly what RTTI is for, any alternative solutions will, by necessity, be uglier.

```
virtual bool operator == (const Shape &Other) const {
    if(typeid(Other) == typeid(*this))
    {
        const Circle& other = static_cast<const Circle&>(Other);
        // ...
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

From a performance point of view:
`typeid` tends to be cheap, a simple lookup of a pointer stored in the virtual table. You can cheaply compare dynamic types for equality.

Then, once you know you have the right type, you can safely use `static_cast`.

`dynamic_cast` has a reputation for being slow (that is, slow as in "compared to virtual function calls", not slow as in "compared to a cast in java"), because it will also analyze the class hierarchy to deal with inheritance (and multiple inheritance, too). You don't need to deal with that here.

Comment: Yes I believe typeid has a constant time cost, where dynamic_cast does not and has to traverse the whole type hierarchy. This is a very nice way to do it without using dynamic_cast

Comment: It's not only that you "don't need to" use dynamic_cast here, you **must not**. Otherwise if MagicCircle inherits from Circle then you would get cases where `circle==magic_circle` and `magic_circle!=circle`.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it can be done without using `typeid` and casting. But it is a bit cumbersome so you must decide if it's worth doing.

### **Version one - double visitors**

Use [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

```
class ShapeVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visitCircle(Circle const &) = 0;
    virtual void visitRectangle(Rectangle const &) = 0;
    // other shapes
}
```

To class `Shape` add

```
virtual void acceptVisitor(ShapeVisitor &) = 0;
```

And visitors

```
class CircleComparingVisitor : public ShapeVisitor
{
    Circle const & lhs; // shorthand for left hand side
    bool equal; // result of comparison
public:
    CircleComparingVisitor(Circle const & circle):lhs(circle), equal(false){}
    virtual void visitCircle(Circle const & rhs) {equal = lhs.radius == rhs.radius;}
    virtual void visitRectangle(Rectangle const &) {}
    // other shapes
    bool isEqual() const {return equal;}
}
// other shapes analogically

class ShapeComparingVisitor
{
    Shape const & rhs; // right hand side
    bool equal;
public:
    ShapeComparingVisitor(Shape const & rhs):rhs(rhs), equal(false) {}

    bool isEqual() const {return equal;}

    virtual void visitCircle(Circle const & lhs)
    {
        CircleComparingVisitor visitor(lhs);
        rhs.accept(visitor);
        equal = visitor.isEqual();
    }
    virtual void visitRectangle(Rectangle const & lhs)
    {
        RectangleComparingVisitor visitor(lhs);
        rhs.accept(visitor);
        equal = visitor.isEqual();
    }
}
```

Finally `operator==` no need to be virtual

```
bool Shape::operator==(const Shape &rhs) const
{
    ShapeComparingVisitor visitor(rhs);
    this->accept(visitor);
    return visitor->isEqual();
}
```

Second thought - `operator==` may be virtual and use a proper comparing visitor - so you can get rid of `ShapeComparingVisitor`

### **Version two - double dispatching**

You add to `Shape`

```
virtual bool compareToCircle(Circle const &) const == 0;
virtual bool compareToRectangle(Rectangle const &) const == 0;
```

And implement in specific shapes

Now for example

```
bool Circle::operator==(Shape const & rhs) const
{
    return rhs.compareToCircle(*this);
}
```

Comment: Yeh I think these are the only solutions that truly don't use and of the RTTI. They are however, as you say, rather cumbersome, and involve every Shape derivative knowing about every other Shape type. Each time you add a new Shape you end having to edit multiple classes, and is a really a pain. Thanks for your suggestions though, they are an interesting read

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what RTTI is for. At compile time all you know is that it's a `Shape&`, so you simply have to do a runtime check to see what derived type it actually is before you can make a meaningful comparison. I'm not aware of any other way to do it without violating polymorphism.

You could define many free functions for `operator ==` for different derived type combinations, but it then wouldn't have polymorphic behaviour as you're presumably handling these via `Shape&` pointers so even the calling code doesn't actually know what type the objects are.

Thus, RTTI is (almost) unavoidable here, and indeed this kind of scenario is exactly why RTTI exists. It's only considered bad practice in some cases because it adds a certain fragility (you have to make sure you handle when things aren't of a type you know how to deal with, because anybody could come along and make a new subclass of `Shape`), and it adds a runtime cost. But you're already paying a runtime cost by using virtual methods.

I say 'almost unavoidable' because you could probably concoct some system which made further virtual method calls on the object passed in to `operator ==` to get the right kind of comparison behaviour, but in practical terms another virtual method lookup (remember, virtual methods also have a runtime performance penalty because the compiler has no idea which implementation will get called so can't put in a concrete function address) is probably no faster than the cost of the RTTI.

If anybody knows a way to do it without that cost at all, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Yes I thought that was the case. I's a bit of a shame, and I think a dynamic_cast does cost more than a virtual function call. I guess it's just one of those un-avoidable things about the language

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that there is a fundamental violation of the Liskov substitution principle going on here, as you're digging into the internal representations of the objects. However if you're happy to expose the internal representation of your objects (or you have to do so for other reasons) then something like this will work.

```
class Shape
{
   virtual void std::string serialize() const =0;
   bool operator==( const Shape & s )
   {
      return this.serialize() == s.serialize();
   }
};
```

Comment: "My feeling is that there is a fundamental violation of the Liskov substitution principle going on here, as you're digging into the internal representations of the objects." So how do you propose to test for equality without violating that? Or are you saying you should never check for equality between polymorphic objects?