# what is a reason for which RTTI is considered as a bad design?

Tags: c++

what is a reason for which RTTI is considered as a bad design?
Stroustrup has written in his book TC++PL that the most common case of usage RTTI technique is with switch instruction, when one want to decide what code should be executed basing on what is a "real" type of a passed object. There is given an example in which an object of shape class was passed to the function and different actions were executed depending on that whether a shape is circle, square, triangle, etc. He has written that such construction is a sign that one should replace the switch-case sequence by virtual functions.

Comment: Dupe? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332075/comparing-polymorphic-base-types-in-c-without-rtti

Comment: That's completely not a dupe at all.

Answer (score 2):

RTTI only works if your classes have a virtual table. If you have a virtual table you can implement virtual functions. The reason you should use virtual functions over a switch on the type of the object is that it works better with inheritance chains, and is less fragile when adding new classes.

For example:

```
class A : public V {}
class B : public V{}

void do_something( const V & v )
{
  if (typeid(A) == typeid(v)) { .. its an A .. }
  if (typeid(B) == typeid(v)) { .. its a B .. }
}

int main()
{
   do_something( A() ); 
   do_something( B() );
}
```

Now if we add a new class `C` also derived from `V` and call `do_something( C() )` (without changing the implementation of `do_something`) , nothing will happen. (No error at compile time). If we add a class `D` derived from `A` also no error and nothing happens.

Contrast this with the behaviour for virtual functions

```
struct V 
{
   virtual void do_something() const =0;
};

struct A
{
  virtual void do_something() const { ... its an A ... }
}

struct B
{
  virtual void do_somethine() const { ... its a B ... }
}

void do_something( const V & v )
{
  v.do_something();
}
```

Now if we derive `C` from `V` and don't implement `C::do_something()` we'll get a compile time error. If we derive `D` from `A` and dont implent `D::do_something()` we'll get calls to `A::do_something()`.

So this is the primary reason virtual functions are prefered over RTTI. However sometimes you may feel that the behaviuor of `do_something` doesn't belong in your `V` or `A B C` classes. So you'd be tempted to use RTTI (either by `typeid` or `dynamic_cast`). A better solution is often to implement the visitor pattern for the class hierarchy.

Comment: Note, I've intentionally ommitted virtual destructors. And am not explaining that `C` doesn't need to implement its pure virtual functions if it is only going to be used as a base class for other classes.

Comment: While the basic idea to replace the if chain with virtual methods is correct, the if chain could be improved by writing it as if (...) else if (...) {...} else if (...) {...} else assert(false); to get a runtime error instead of a "nothing". Thus, sooner or later a missing implementation will be noticed, and you will immediately know where something is missing.